# Trying to force WWW and HTPS and only two out of my three rules will work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Not working for me .. what am I doing wrong I get the dreaded too many redirects error. I am trying to force all my urls to WWW and https

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^all-service-musical.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.all-service-musical.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^asmusic.org [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.all-service-musical.com/$1 [r=301]

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.all-service-musical.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.all-service-musical.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

The first two rules work fine together, but the 3rd rule to try to change the www url to https breaks the whole thing.... any ideas?

I also tried removing all the above code and tried to accomplish the http to https portion of the task by using:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I also get a too many redirects error also when using this approach

5/7/2019 .. Well no solutions found yet, but able to work around it for now by using a rewrite rule to direct everything to the non WWW version. Maybe someday someone will post a probable solution to the issue and I will add the WWW back. The main reason for what I was attempting is that the google links from searches pointed to the WWW version and they were coming up unsecured where the non WWW version would come up secure.

Comment: "^www.all-service-musical.com" matches both HTTP and HTTPS. So, you redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, and then try to redirect to HTTPS again...

Comment: I see what you are saying, but how in the heck do i get around this so when www.all-service-musical is typed in the address bar it points to the https site?

Comment: A quick update .. no resolve found as of yet I have tried just about every piece of code I can locate on the internet to rewrite everything to https and Most everything breaks the page with too many redirects.
As Network solutions crashed my site as well as thousands of others for 3 days I talked them into giving me free paid support for a month …. Should be interesting to see what they come up with.
Of course I have everything backed up in case they totally mess things up. I will post the results here when I get them so that maybe I can spare someone some greif.

Answer (score 0):

Okay .. 2 months later I have a solution

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^all-service-musical.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.all-service-musical.com/$1 [R=302,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)  https://www.all-service-musical.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Note in the first rule I forwarded to http rather than https to avoid a potential endless redirect when the 2nd rule is processed .. may work with https as well, but I figured I would leave well enough alone as I had a working rule at that point. – again using Network Solutions as my host so some of this may be related to their system.

Hopefully this information will save someone else a bit of time and aggravation.